Split strings from command output in Powershell
I work with Perforce and often have many local changes after unshelving that I want to remove. Using PowerShell I can print out the files I want removed but the output string still contains substrings I would like to see removed.
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include ("*.uasset", "*.umap") -Attributes !ReadOnly "C:\Unreal\Project\Content" | ForEach-Object {p4 have $_.FullName}

This will output files I only have locally as "C:\Unreal\Project\File.uasset - file(s) not on client." and others as "//Project/Content/File.uasset#12 - C:\Unreal\Project\File.uasset"
The files I don't have on client I want to Remove-Items on, and the other run p4 sync but am currently stuck even getting Write-Host to output either with only the local path.
I've tried filtering the outputs using Select-String, to then attempt and only output the paths like
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include ("*.uasset", "*.umap") -Attributes !ReadOnly "C:\Unreal\Project\Content" | ForEach-Object {p4 have $_.FullName} | Select-String " not on client." | Write-Host ($_ -split ' - file(s)')[0]

The full string "C:\Unreal\Project\File.uasset - file(s) not on client." still gets printed
Also attemped filtering inside the loop like this
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include ("*.uasset", "*.umap") -Attributes !ReadOnly "C:\Unreal\Project\Content" | ForEach-Object { if ((p4 have $_.FullName) -like "*not on client." { Write-Host ($_ -split ' - file(s)')[0] } }

Again, full string is printed to terminal.
I have tried variation of split like $_.Split(' - file(s)', 2)[0] but still full string gets printed. And just to make sure, I tried different indices if it was the case that split would have full string as first index then have results of split.
Example of unfiltered output
> Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include ("*.uasset", "*.umap") -Attributes !ReadOnly "C:\Unreal\Project\Content" | ForEach-Object {p4 have $_.FullName}
C:\Unreal\Project\Content\Example_01.uasset - file(s) not on client.
C:\Unreal\Project\Content\Example_02.uasset - file(s) not on client.
C:\Unreal\Project\Content\Example_03.uasset - file(s) not on client.
//Project/Content/Example_04.uasset#11 - C:\Unreal\Project\Content\Example_04.uasset
//Project/Content/Example_05.uasset#6 - C:\Unreal\Project\Content\Example_05.uasset
//Project/Content/Example_06.uasset#1 - C:\Unreal\Project\Content\Example_06.uasset
//Project/Content/Example_07.umap#7 - C:\Unreal\Project\Content\Example_07.umap
//Project/Content/Example_08.umap#73 - C:\Unreal\Project\Content\Example_08.umap
C:\Unreal\Project\Content\Example_09.uasset - file(s) not on client.
C:\Unreal\Project\Content\Example_10.uasset - file(s) not on client.
C:\Unreal\Project\Content\Example_11.uasset - file(s) not on client.
C:\Unreal\Project\Content\Example_12.uasset - file(s) not on client.
C:\Unreal\Project\Content\Example_13.uasset - file(s) not on client.

Guess one could note also, that the p4 command have will print the "file(s) not on client" to stderr as this is an error/warning - found after I gave up on powershell and just did it in python.

Can you add an exact example of the unfiltered output, copied from the console window? I. e. just Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include ("*.uasset", "*.umap") -Attributes !ReadOnly "C:\Unreal\Project\Content" | ForEach-Object {p4 have $_.FullName}

Could it be that you need to escape the parentheses in the expression you are splitting on? Do you get the result you want if splitting on ' - file\(s\)' instead of on ' - file(s)'?

wouldn't be better to have the string manipulation and write-host inside the Foreach-Obhect?

@zett42 Added example of full output

@sirtao I did try doing the string manipulation inside the foreach, third code snippet - or what do you mean?

syntax in third snippet is broken btw. But I meant different: try these as foreach: ForEach-Object { (p4 have $_.FullName ).where({ $_ -like '*not on client.' }).split('- file(s)') } and ForEach-Object { (p4 have $_.FullName ) } | Where-Object { $_ -like '*not on client.' } | ForEach-Object { $_ -split '- file(s)' } | Where-Object { $_ }

@sirtao still not getting it to work but might be due to that p4 have will print the string I attempt to split to stderr and not stdout

in that case  (p4 have $_.FullName 2>&1) (redirecting the stdErr stream to the stdOut thus the regular pipeline) should resolve the issue

@sirtao thanks, this worked ForEach-Object {p4 have $_.FullName 2>&1 } | Where-Object { $_ -like '*not on client.'} | ForEach-Object { ($_ -split ' - file\(s\)')[0] }
Seems I also needed to escape parentheses like @meliasson suggested.

The -F flag on p4 makes a lot of this string parsing unnecessary.  See https://workshop.perforce.com/files/guest/sam_stafford/doc/p4blog/2013.2%20Fun%20with%20Formatting.txt

also: are you sure you don't just want the p4 clean command, which automatically removes local (unopened) changes...?

@Samwise p4 clean does not seem to do what I am looking for, running it in a folder where I have made local edits by setting the files as writable, not checking it out. In Unreal you can set files as writable even when not having them marked for edit.

p4 clean is for exactly that use case and will revert those files to their depot versions if they have local changes -- it uses checksum comparison rather than relying on the writable bit, so if you made it writable but didn't modify it then it won't be touched.  If the files are actually open then p4 revert deals with them, but clean is specifically for changed but unopened files.  Try p4 clean -n //... to preview what a "clean" of your whole workspace looks like.

Putting together everbody's efforts:
# Get the files
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include ('*.uasset', '*.umap') -Attributes !ReadOnly 'C:\Unreal\Project\Content' |
    # run "p4 have" on every file
    # we are only interested in the results sent to stdErr\Error Stream, so redirect it to stdOut\Success Stream
    ForEach-Object { p4 have $_.FullName 2>&1 } | 
    # Filter keeping only the ones we need
    Where-Object { $_ -like '*not on client.' } | 
    # for each string, remove the undesidered parts(everything after the filename)
    ForEach-Object { $_.Substring($_.IndexOf(' - file(s)')) }

It returns a string array of filenames with full path
